# DataTemplateSelector / Binding does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datatemplate, datatemplateselector

This is my ViewModel:

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private CalculatorViewModel calc;
    public CalculatorViewModel Calculator {get {return calc; }set {calc = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Calculator");}}
}

class CalculatorViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private CalculatorMode mode;
    public CalculatorMode Mode {get {return mode;}set{mode=value; RaisePropertyChanged("CalculatorMode");}}

    public CalculatorViewModel()
    {
        Mode = new HexMode();
    }
}
abstract class CalculatorMode : ViewModelBase
{
    abstract int Calculate(...);
}
class HexMode : CalculatorMode
{
public int Calculate(...) { ...}
}
```

This is my MainWindow (a MainViewModel instance is set to the Windows´ DataContext):

```
<ad:DockingManager >
            <ad:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplateSelector>
                <vm:PanesTemplateSelector>
                    <vm:PanesTemplateSelector.FileViewTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <h:MyDocument  />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </vm:PanesTemplateSelector.FileViewTemplate>
                    <vm:PanesTemplateSelector.CalculatorViewTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <w:Calculator  />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </vm:PanesTemplateSelector.CalculatorViewTemplate>
                </vm:PanesTemplateSelector>
            </ad:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplateSelector>
</ad:DockingManager>
```

Code of PanesTemplateSelector-Class:

```
public DataTemplate FileViewTemplate
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public DataTemplate CalculatorViewTemplate
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public override System.Windows.DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, System.Windows.DependencyObject container)
        {
            if (item is DocumentViewModel)
                return FileViewTemplate;

            if (item is CalcualtorViewModel)
                return CalculatorViewTemplate;

            return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
        }
```

Content of the Calculator-Control:

```
<Grid Name="main">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ContentControl Name="content">
        <ContentControl.ContentTemplateSelector>
            <vm:CalculatorTemplateSelector>
                <vm:CalculatorTemplateSelector.DefaultView>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="Dummy for normal view" Foreground="Wheat" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </vm:CalculatorTemplateSelector.DefaultView>
                <vm:CalculatorTemplateSelector.HexView>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="Dummy für Hexview" Foreground="Gray"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </vm:CalculatorTemplateSelector.HexView>
            </vm:CalculatorTemplateSelector>
        </ContentControl.ContentTemplateSelector>
    </ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

Code of the CalculatorTemplateSelector-Class:

```
public DataTemplate HexView
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public DataTemplate DefaultView
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public override System.Windows.DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, System.Windows.DependencyObject container)
        {
            CalculatorViewModel cjmv = (CalculatorViewModel)item;

            if (cjmv != null)
            {
                if (cjmv.Mode is HexMode)
                    return HexView;

        return DefaultView;
            }

            return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
        }
```

The first TemplateSelector is working. The right Template is chosen and I can see the Calculator-Control. But the TemplateSelector in the Calculator-Control is not working. In CalculatorTemplateSelector.SelectTemplate the item-parameter is null all the time. But i need there the CalculatorViewModel-instance. I guess my problem is a binding issue, but I don´t get to a solution. Any ideas?

Comment: Sheldon Cooper.. asking a question! Oh my days! How is Amy? :P
Anyway since your question is probably answered.. you may want to change this line `CalculatorViewModel cjmv = (CalculatorViewModel)item;` to `CalculatorViewModel cjmv = item as CalculatorViewModel;` Otherwise an exception may be thrown..

Comment: +1 for Sheldon Cooper asking a question !

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr but one thing is for sure :

```
public CalculatorMode Mode [...] RaisePropertyChanged("CalculatorMode");}}
```

should be : `RaisePropertyChanged("Mode");}}`

Answer (score 0):

I may ask, but only to take you part of my brilliancy... I just found a solution myself:
Adding the DataContext-Binding to a ContentPresenter (instead of ContentControl)

```
<ContentPresenter Name="content" DataContext="{Binding}">
```

and change the SelectTemplate-Implementation to:

```
 public override System.Windows.DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, System.Windows.DependencyObject container)
        {
            ContentPresenter cp = container as ContentPresenter;
            if (cp != null)
            {
                CalculatorViewModel model = cp.DataContext as CalculatorViewModel;
                if (model != null)
                {
                    if (model.Mode is DefaultMode)
                        return DefaultView;
                    if (model.Mode is HexMode)
                        return HexView;
                }
            }
            return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
        }
```

Anyway, thanks for the notice of the wrong RaisePropertyChanged-Call